# Gaussian expectation for a rational function

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution, expectation, gaussian-integral

Suppose $X_1, X_2, ..., X_N$ are i.i.d with Gaussian distribution with unit mean and variance $\sigma^2$,  can we find the following expectation ?

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{1}{1+X_1^2+X_2^2+...+X_N^2}\right]
\end{equation}

Actually I wanted to calculate following expectation, then I realized I need that :

\begin{align}
&\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{X_1^2+X_2^2+...+X_N^2}{1+X_1^2+X_2^2+...+X_N^2}\right]\\
&\qquad=\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{1+X_1^2+X_2^2+...+X_N^2}{1+X_1^2+X_2^2+...+X_N^2}\right]-\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{1}{1+X_1^2+X_2^2+...+X_N^2}\right]\\
&\qquad=1-\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{1}{1+X_1^2+X_2^2+...+X_N^2}\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Do you know about the non-central chi-squared distribution?

Comment: @kimchilover I know, but I am actually looking into expectation of inverse of (Chi-Square +1)

Comment: So you have a 1 dimensional integral: a rational function integrated against a gamma-ish density thing.  I guess I'm asking, have you written out such an integral and checked conditions for convergence, and checked for its presence in handbooks of definite integrals?  Can you do the same for the central chi-squared distribution, as a warm up exercise?

Comment: @kimchilover I believ I have looked at that before, I 'll try it again with more devotion, I thought I may be missing something obvious and somebody can help me.

Comment: Just for reference, we have $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1+X_1^2+\cdots+X_N^2}\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{(1+2\sigma^2t)^{N/2}}\,dt.$$ This integral can be represented in terms of incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 2):

Using my favorite trick:
$$F(a)=\int dX_1 \cdots dX_N {e^{-a\sum X^2_i}\over{1+\sum X^2_i}}$$
$$F(a)={1\over 1-{d\over da}}\int dX_1 \cdots dX_N e^{-a\sum X^2_i}$$
$$(1-{d\over da})F(a)=\int dX_1 \cdots dX_N e^{-a\sum X^2_i} $$
define
$$F(a)=u(a)e^{a}$$
and we get 
$$u'(a)e^{a}=C\int dX_1 \cdots dX_N e^{-a\sum X^2_i}=C a^{-N/2}$$
$$u'(a)=e^{-a}a^{-N/2}$$
$$F(a)=C e^a \int_a da' e^{-a'}a'^{-N/2}$$
setting $a=1$ will give the required integral